# How can DataGrip test the stored procedures of Oracle database?

Tags: datagrip

In the DataGrip software, I have connected to an Oracle database and I want to test a stored procedure and I don't find the corresponding function, such as "test"

See the official website document operation did not succeed [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/debugging-code.html](https://stackoverflow.com) Please guide me

Comment: This should help:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-oracle-pl-sql-code.html

Comment: not userful @Koyasha

Comment: To test you perhaps need to use utPLSQL
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/run-utplsql-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

To run utPLSQL tests, you need to create a Run Configuration for utPLSL where you can specify Paths and Tags.

[image: config utPLSQL]
[image: run tests]

For step-by-step guidance, please refer to the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/run-utplsql-tests.html#run-utplsql-tests-by-using-a-run-configuration)